# Spring Validation with Google App Engine, preserving errors after redirect causing NotSerializedException

Tags: java, spring, validation, google-app-engine

I am building an ecommerce clothing application.  I am trying to preserve the errors after a redirect.  I should note I had this working with tomcat as my web server, I am migrating to Google App Engine and am getting serialization issues.

In my controller I have a method like this

```
    @Autowired
@Qualifier("productDetailValidator")
private Validator validator;

@InitBinder("productDetail")
private void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
        binder.setValidator(validator);
    }
@RequestMapping(value="/add-to-cart", method = RequestMethod.POST)  
public String submitForm(@RequestParam("id") Integer productId,
        @ModelAttribute("productDetail") @Validated ProductDetail productDetail, BindingResult result, 
        RedirectAttributes redir, Principal auth, Model model) {  


    String view = null;
    User user = null;
    Product product = null;
    if(result.hasErrors()) {
        user = userService.findUser(name);
        product = productService.findProduct(productId);
        redir.addFlashAttribute("org.springframework.validation.BindingResult.productDetail", result);

        redir.addFlashAttribute(...,...); // I add about 5 attributes to the flashmap besides BindingResult

        return "redirect:/product";
    }
}
```

Besides the binding result I have to preserve some details about the page like the current product being viewed, cart total, signed in user, etc

And here is my validate method inside my validator

```
 public void validate(Object obj, Errors errors) {

    ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmptyOrWhitespace(errors, "quantity", "valid.quantity", "Please enter a quantity");
    ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmptyOrWhitespace(errors, "size", "valid.size", "Please select a size.");
    ProductDetail productDetail = (ProductDetail) obj;

    if(productDetail.getColor().equalsIgnoreCase("default")){
        errors.rejectValue("color", "valid.color", "Please select a color.");
    }
    if(productDetail.getQuantity() <= 0){
        errors.rejectValue("quantity", "minimum.quantity", "Please select quantity greater than 0.");
    }
}
```

I get this error now

```
java.io.NotSerializableException:org.springframework.format.support.DefaultFormattingConversionService
```

I cannot find much information about this issue - its pretty trivial, DefaultFormattingConversionService class does not implement Serializable, but I don't have access to that class as its part of Spring's framework.

If I take the BindingResult out of the flashmap the application works without error, when running with a debugger I can see all errors are being found, just not displayed when they are supposed to.

Thank you